# Dart - Split String with Regex and keep the delimiter

Tags: regex, dart

I have following string :

```dart
final String text = """
This is first text <link="www.stackoverflow.com">First Hello</link>
This is the second text <link="www.stackoverflow.com">Second</link>
"""
```

I wanted to split the string and get the following result :

```dart
[
"This is first text ", 
"<link="www.stackoverflow.com">First Hello</link>", 
"This is the second text ", 
"<link="www.stackoverflow.com">Second</link>"
]
```

I tried using this regex but it's not as expected :

```dart
(?<=<link=".*">)|(?=</link>)
```

This is the result :

[image]

Can i split like this using Regex and how is the regex format?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it `<lnk>` or `<link>`. Your text uses the former, the regexp uses the latter. Also, what is the `haha` in the expectations, and where did the newlines go?

Comment: It should be `link`. Already edit it. In the picture i used different text example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. Try:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r'(?=<link=".*?">)|(?<=</link>)');
```

It has two differences from your RegExp:

- It swaps the `(?=` and `(?<=` because you want a split *before* a `<link...>`, so you want a look*ahead* for that, and after a `</link>`, so a look*behind* for that.
- I added the `?` to `".*?"`, because otherwise it could potentially match until a later `"` on the same line, instead of the first one. Your example didn't have that, but better safe than sorry.

With that, you get the strings:

1. `"This is first text "`
2. `"<link=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">First Hello</link>"`
3. `"\nThis is the second text "`
4. `"<link=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">Second</link>"`
5. `"\n"`

If you don't want the newlines to be included, you should probably remove them first.

if you want to combine the `\n` with the `</link>`, you can change the RegExp to

```dart
var re = RegExp(r'(?=<link=".*?">)|(?<=</link>\n*(?<=\n))');
```

That gives you:

1. `"This is first text "`
2. `"<link=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">First Hello</link>\n"`
3. `"This is the second text "`
4. `"<link=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">Second</link>\n"`

Comment: Hi @Irn thanks you helped me again. I tried and it's working. This is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dart example

```
void main() {
  final String pattern = r'(?=<em>.*?)|(?<=</em>)';
  final RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  final String text = "a<em>b</em>c<em>d</em>e";
  final List<String> result = text.split(regExp);

  print(result); // [a, <em>b</em>, c, <em>d</em>, e]
}
```